# proof of rudin Theorem $2.37$ - infinite subset of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having a problem with the proof of this theorem in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

> **$2.37$ Theorem:** If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in K.
>
> **Proof:** If no point of $K$ were a limit point of $E$, then each $q\in K$ would have a neighborhood $V_q$ which contains at most one point of $E$. It is clear that no finite subcollection of ${V_q}$ can cover $E$; and the same is true of $K$, since $E\subset K$. This contradicts the compactness of $K$.

My problem is this: Doesn't what is shown only disprove the compactness of $E$ (given the assumption that no limit point exists)? For it to contradict the compactness of $K$, I thought that we would first have to prove that $\cup \{V_q \}$ is an open cover of $K$, because then we would have found an open cover of K with no finite subcover, which clearly contradicts the compactness of $K$. I can imagine a counterexample where $\cup \{V_q\}$ is not an open cover of $K$, so What am I missing?

Comment: It is an open cover of $K$. The cover is the collection $\{\,V_q \mid  q\in K\,\}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This follows from the construction: You choose a neigbourhood $V_q$ for *each* point $q \in K$. So, since $q \in V_q$, we have $K \subseteq \bigcup_{q \in K} V_q$.

Comment: I see that I was thinking about the proof in a completely incorrect way (only considering the $q\in E$). Thanks!